# Access as admin with mongo client ok, fails with mongorestore

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

Using the mongo client, I can authenticate successfully with my admin account:

```
$ mongo -u my_admin_username -p my_admin_pass --authenticationDatabase admin
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3
connecting to: test
>
```

but when I try to execute `mongorestore` with the same credentials, it fails:

```
$ mongorestore -u my_admin_username -p my_admin_pass /backup/20140821/db/myproject/
connected to: 127.0.0.1
assertion: 13 not authorized on admin to execute command { getParameter: 1, authSchemaVersion: 1 }
```

Why is that? What am I missing? I'd like to execute successfully a mongorestore.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ mongorestore -u my_admin_username -p my_admin_pass /backup/20140821/db/myproject/ -db myproject
```

This worked.

Comment: this doesn't work for me assertion: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 }